# Iterate storage maps inside an offchain worker

Tags: pallet, rpc, offchain-worker

I need to iterate over the following double map inside an offchain worker:

[image]

How can I access this map outside the pallet assets? Can I use an RPC method to get all the values  for that double map inside an offchain worker?

It should be done with  fn iter_key_prefix() from the IterableStorageDoubleMap trait?

Answer (score 0):

Are you still running into this issue?

I believe you can do something like this:

```
#[pallet::hooks]
impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
    fn offchain_worker(now: T::BlockNumber) {
        YourStorageMapHere::<T>::iter().for_each(|v| {
            // Do things with the iterated values `v` in here
        });
    }
}
```

Bear in mind the usual considerations when developing around offchain workers, for example, not trusting the offchain worker.